# Can't get my django program to increment values that are on the server

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am very new to Django and I found a lot on other sites but nothing that really could help me. I am making a movie rating app that has a slider that controls how many stars you want to give a movie it then takes that number and adds it to the grand total of stars and then takes the number of votes and finds the average number of stars for the movie. Right now I can not get the values that are stored on the server ie total number of stars and total number of votes to update with the submit button.

currently here is my template form

```
                           <form  action="{% url 'polls:vote' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                            <input action="/vote/" name="myvote" related-image-id="votes{{movie.Movie_Title}}" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="0" oninput="mySlider(this)">
                            <input type="submit" value="Vote!"/>
                        </form>
```

here is my Url text

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name ='polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
data=Movies.objects.order_by('-pub_date')


for movie in data:
    if movie.Total_Number_of_Votes==0:
        movie.avg="No one has voted for this yet be the first"
    else:
        movie.avg=movie.Total_Number_of_Stars/movie.Total_Number_of_Votes

return TemplateResponse(request, 'polls/index.html', {"data": data})

def vote(self, request):
    movie=get_object_or_404(Movies)
    thisVote=movie.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['myvote'])

   movie.Total_Number_of_Stars=movie.Total_Number_of_Stars+ thisVote
   movie.Total_Number_of_Stars.save()
   movie.Total_Number_of_Votes += 1
   movie.Total_Number_of_Votes.save()
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(request, 'polls:index.html'))
```

I have my impression that it is something to do with the HttpResponse but I am not sure I am very new to all of this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so first of all you have a big problem on your `vote` view.

- It isn't taking in any movie identifier as a parameter, so your submit button is never going to act upon the movie you're actually voting on.
- On the line `movie=get_object_or_404(Movies)`, your calling the `Movies` class, not an actual movie instance from the database.

This is what your view should look like.

```
def vote(request, pk):  # pk would be the Movie's primary key (id)
    movie=get_object_or_404(Movies, pk=pk)  # This makes the movie var an ACTUAL movie
    thisVote=movie.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['myvote'])

    movie.Total_Number_of_Stars=movie.Total_Number_of_Stars+ thisVote
    movie.Total_Number_of_Votes += 1
    movie.save()  # Need to save the movie object and only once
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(request, 'polls:index.html'))
```

And since you're changing the functions parameters, you also need to change the urlconf.

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),  # Needs to be explicit
```

Comment: I tried this now and it doesn't seem to work. I the submit button seems to just cause the page to refresh and it will now add a question value in the URL